# Best pratice for null verifications of multiple fields

Tags: php

There is a moment in my program that I arrived in the following condition:

```
if ($Student->getClass() != null) {
    if ($Student>getClass()->isActive()) {
        if ($Student->getClass()->getAcceptedGrades() != null) {
            if (in_array($StudentGrade, $Student->getClass()->getAcceptedGrades())) { 
                echo "The student has a acceptable grade."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ask myself if there is not a better way of doing this kind of verification.

I can not try to verify a value in a null object, so I always need to verify if I have the object I am accessing.

Comment: Can you add more background and more relevant concrete code please. Right now it's hard to understand what you are asking. What exactly is $object1 and $object2?

Comment: Shouldn't this go to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Gordon, I used a better example to exemplify it

Comment: Note that in some languages, there is an operator for that. For instance in C# you'd write `if (student?.GetClass()?.GetAcceptedGrades() != null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you methods return null, you will have these checks.

You could use this [PHP port of java.util.Optional](https://github.com/Ocramius/ocramius.util.Optional), but that would still require you to have checks everywhere. It looks somewhat nicer though.

[But the real issue is really returning null](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare). For instance, your

```
$Student->getClass()->getAcceptedGrades()
```

apparently returns either `null` or an `array`. If that method would always return an empty array instead of null, you could get rid of the null check before the call to `in_array`. In general, it is good practise for a method to return one thing and only that one thing. That prevents consuming code on having to check the return values.

If you change `getAcceptedGrades` to always return an array, you are left with

```
if ($Student->getClass() != null) {
    if ($Student>getClass()->isActive()) {
        if (in_array($StudentGrade, $Student->getClass()->getAcceptedGrades())) { 
            echo "The student has an acceptable grade."
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all of your if checks basically operate on whatever `getClass` returns. I assume, it's a Class/Course object. The bad thing about it is, that the code containing these if checks knows the conditions to verify the acceptable grade. When instead the Course object should be the expert on that because it contains the information for it. So why not just add a method `hasAcceptableGrade()` to the Course object?

```
public function hasAcceptableGrade($StudentGrade)
{
    return $this->isActive()
        && in_array($StudentGrade, $this->getAcceptedGrades());
}
```

This way, your code having the if checks doesn't need to know the details how an accepted grade is calculated. Instead it just asks the Course object, which will leave you with

```
if ($Student->getClass() != null) {
    if ($Student->getClass()->hasAcceptableGrade($StudentGrade) {
        echo "The student has an acceptable grade."
    }
}
```

To get rid of the final null check, you would again make sure to always return a Class/Course object. If that is not possible, because the student isn't enrolled, either have `getClass` raise a `StudentNotEnrolled` exception and change the code to

```
try {
    if ($Student->getClass()->hasAcceptableGrade($StudentGrade) {
        echo "The student has an acceptable grade."
    }
} catch (StudentNotEnrolledException $e) {
    echo "Student is not enrolled"
}
```

or introduce a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for this case, e.g.

```
class NullCourse
{
    public function hasAcceptableGrade($StudentGrade)
    {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

We are always returning false here, because we assume a student with no course will never have an acceptable grade for a course. If you don't want to follow that logic, you can change that obviously to be always true or to raise the `StudentNotEnrolledException` here.

With the return value of false, this reduces your code to

```
if ($Student->getClass()->hasAcceptableGrade($StudentGrade) {
    echo "The student has an acceptable grade."
}
```

Now the only thing left is to move the `hasAccetableGrade` method onto the Student object so your consuming code can simply ask the Student object, instead of knowing that it first need to fetch the Course object. I omit the example code for this. You'll end up with

```
if ($Student->hasAcceptableGrade($StudentGrade) {
    echo "The student has an acceptable grade."
}
```

Just one if. No multiple conditions. And no Null checks.

Comment: It seems very reasonable. Thanks @Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

Put a function that does this for you into the student class.

```
class Student {
    public function hasEmptyClass() {
        $class = $this->getClass();
        if (! $class instanceof Class || ! $class->hasAcceptableGrade(...)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And then another method on the Class/Course object for the Accepted Grades? And then another method on X for Y and so on? I'd rather keep the null checks then before I'd go that route.

Comment: @Gordon depends on the relation and amount of things to check. If the checks relate to something common, this is what I would do.